# How to use LIMIT clause with offset and number of rows in Laravel query builder?

Tags: laravel-4, query-builder

I have a statement similar to the one below, in Laravel:

```
$tiles = Tile::with('comments', 'user', 'category', 'ratings')
    ->take($startRow, 15)
    ->get();
return Response::json($tiles);
```

But this just limited the number of rows returned and did not take into account the offset. I tried replacing the `take` statement with `select(DB::raw('LIMIT(' . $startRow . ',15)'))` but this produced a SQL syntax error.

So how can I add a `LIMIT :startRow, 15` clause to the end of my SQL query using Laravel's query builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try this. the `skip()` method is for offsets

```
$tiles = Tile::with('comments', 'user', 'category', 'ratings')
             ->take(15)
             ->skip($startRow)
             ->get();
return Response::json($tiles);
```

Read more about [skip](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/).

Comment: Yes, this worked! I can't believe I didn't notice the `skip()` function, it was right in the docs D: